# Hostapd not starting despite successful startup message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hostapd

I have Hostapd running on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.  It's set to run as a service, or so I thought.

Whenever I reboot the system, the status indicates it's running properly.

```
root@beelink:~# service hostapd status
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-11-04 00:57:49 UTC; 39s ago
    Process: 919 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE>
   Main PID: 1028 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4434)
     Memory: 2.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─1028 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B /root/ap/hostapd.conf

Nov 04 00:57:48 beelink systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
Nov 04 00:57:48 beelink hostapd[919]: Configuration file: /root/ap/hostapd.conf
Nov 04 00:57:48 beelink hostapd[919]: Using interface wlx00c0ca989ef3 with hwaddr 00:c0:ca:98:9e:f3 and ssid "testt"
Nov 04 00:57:49 beelink hostapd[919]: wlx00c0ca989ef3: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Nov 04 00:57:49 beelink hostapd[919]: wlx00c0ca989ef3: AP-ENABLED
Nov 04 00:57:49 beelink systemd[1]: Started Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
```

However I do not see my hotstop in any wifi devices.

If I run the following command:
`service hostapd restart`

It works fine and my wifi shows up.  The exact same startup messages show up as under a fresh boot.

Why isn't it working despite the startup logs showing it should be running?